# C# Windows Form: Using List<KeyValuePair> to create a Top 10 Leaderboard

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to create a Top 10 Leaderboard in C# Windows Form, based on player usernames and scores read in from a text file.

E.g. of line in text file:

`Denna~21`

This is my code so far:

```
private void scrnLeaderboard_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] players = FileMethods.ReadLines();

            // Create List<KeyValuePair> to hold all player usernames and scores
            List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> playerNamesScores = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();

            foreach (var item in players)
            {
                string[] playerDetails = item.Split('~');

                if (playerDetails.Length == 2)
                    // Player's username and score added to List<KeyValuePair> playersNamesScores
                    // Key is score, Value is username
                    playerNamesScores.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(Convert.ToInt32(playerDetails[1]), playerDetails[0].ToString()));
            }

            // Sorting the scores in descending order
            var sortedScores = playerNamesScores.OrderByDescending(x => x).ToList<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();

            // Assigning the appropriate values to each label's text on the leaderboard
            lblPos1.Text = String.Format("{0}: \t{1}", sortedScores[0].Value, sortedScores[0].Key);
            lblPos2.Text = String.Format("{0}: \t{1}", sortedScores[1].Value, sortedScores[1].Key);
            lblPos3.Text = String.Format("{0}: \t{1}", sortedScores[2].Value, sortedScores[2].Key);
            lblPos4.Text = String.Format("{0}: \t{1}", sortedScores[3].Value, sortedScores[3].Key);
            lblPos5.Text = String.Format("{0}: \t{1}", sortedScores[4].Value, sortedScores[4].Key);
            lblPos6.Text = String.Format("{0}: \t{1}", sortedScores[5].Value, sortedScores[5].Key);
            lblPos7.Text = String.Format("{0}: \t{1}", sortedScores[6].Value, sortedScores[6].Key);
            lblPos8.Text = String.Format("{0}: \t{1}", sortedScores[7].Value, sortedScores[7].Key);
            lblPos9.Text = String.Format("{0}: \t{1}", sortedScores[8].Value, sortedScores[8].Key);
            lblPos10.Text = String.Format("{0}: \t{1}", sortedScores[9].Value, sortedScores[9].Key);
        }
```

FileMethods.ReadLines() is just this:

```
string filepath = @"previousPlayers.txt";
string[] players = File.ReadLines(filepath).ToArray();
return players;
```

Each time I compile the code, I get this error,
'At least one object must implement IComparable.',
on this line:

```
var sortedScores = playerNamesScores.OrderByDescending(x => x).ToList<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();
```

I'm not sure what this means, or how make my code work.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: It doesn't know how to compare KeyValuePairs.  You have to help and pass a comparer to OrderByDescending() as the 2nd argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OrderByDescending` method sorts items by key, returned by *key selector* (first argument of this method). It then uses these keys of individual items to compare one item with another to decide, which items comes first and which comes later. By default, it uses method of `IComparable` interface implemented by items for this comparison. But you specified `x => x` as a *key selector*, which returns objects of type `KeyValuePair<int, string>`, which does not implement `IComparable`. Thus there is no way to sort them and you get "*At least one object must implement IComparable*" error.

Since all you want is to order items by score (of type `int`) and `int` implements `IComparable`, you can simply use selector that returns score:

```
var sortedScores = playerNamesScores.OrderByDescending(x => x.Key).ToList<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();
```

If more sophisticated way of sorting items is needed (e.g. you need playes with the same score to be sorted alphabetically), you can declare class that implements `IComparer<KeyValuePair<int, string>>` interface and pass it's instance as a second argument of `OrderByDescending` method.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you define x?

```
// Sorting the scores in descending order
var sortedScores = playerNamesScores.OrderByDescending(x => x).ToList<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();
```

In this section, you normally name the variable you want to sort on, but from the examples shown here 'x' seems to just come out of nowhere.

You are trying to sort a KeyValuePair as well, instead of trying to sort on the int or the string.  A KeyValuePair itself isn't sortable.